# Trajectory interpolation with known coordinates and heading angles.

Tags: interpolation, spline

I have a set of $n$ tuples $(t_i,x_i,y_i,r_i)$ for $i \in \{0,...,n\}$, where $t_i$ is a timestamp, $x_i$ and $y_i$ location coordinates and $r_i$ a heading angle of a moving object in 2D space. Note that I do not know the velocity, only the heading angle.

**I would like a continuous interpolation for the time interval $[t_0, t_N]$, i.e. the trajectory of said object. What would be a smart way to do this?**

Here are the steps to my current approach:

1. Estimate velocities $v_i$ using only time and location coordinates:

   1. Fit natural cubic splines $S_x(t)$ to points $(t_i,x_i)$.
   2. Fit natural cubic splines $S_y(t)$ to points $(t_i,y_i)$.
   3. Calculate $x'_i$ and $y'_i$, which are the first derivatives of $S_x$ and $S_y$ at $t_i$, respectively.
   4. Define $v_i$ as $\lVert(x'_i,y'_i)\rVert_2$. Note that vector $(x'_i,y'_i)$ does not point in the direciton of $r_i$.
2. Adjust derivatives, so they point in direction $r_i$

   1. $\tilde{x}'_i := \cos(r_i)*v_i$
   2. $\tilde{y}'_i := \sin(r_i)*v_i$
   3. Vector $(\tilde{x}'_i, \tilde{y}'_i)$ has length $v_i$ and  points in desired direction $r_i$.
3. Estimate overall trajectory

   1. Fit cubic splines $\tilde{S_x}$ using $(t_i,x_i,\tilde{x}'_i$), where the splines should be consistent with $x_i$ and have derivatives $\tilde{x}'_i$ at timestamps $t_i$.
   2. Fit cubic splines $\tilde{S_y}$ using $(t_i,y_i,\tilde{y}'_i$), analogous to $\tilde{S_x}$.
   3. Note that (unlike in the previous cubic splines) we no longer enforce that the second derivative is the same for two connected splines. Instead we enforce specific first derivative values.

**Result:**
$\tilde{S_x}$ and $\tilde{S_y}$ define a continuous trajectory, which are consistent with all $(t_i,x_i,y_i,r_i)$.